# Obtaining distances between hierarchical clusters usin scikit

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, distance

I am currently working in Python using the SciKit module to calculate a series of clusters as

```
Clustering_Jerarquico=linkage(data_state_normalized, 'average', metric='euclidean')

db_index_list = []
num_clusters_list = []
max_distance_list=[]
for i in range(106, -1, -1):
    clusters_provisional = fcluster(Clustering_Jerarquico, t=i, criterion="distance")
    num_clusters = len(set(clusters_provisional))
    db_avg_provisional = davies_bouldin_score(data_state_normalized, clusters_provisional)
    db_index_list.append(db_avg_provisional)
    num_clusters_list.append(num_clusters)
```

I am using the [Davies Bouldin](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score.html) index as a measurement of the optimal amount of clusters by plotting it in a similar way to the [elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)).

as

```
muestraPlot = 1
if muestraPlot == 1:
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(num_clusters_list, db_index_list)
    plt.title(f'Índice de Davis Bouldin_{state.lower()}')
    plt.xlabel('Número de Clusters')
    plt.ylabel('Índice de Davis Bouldin')
    plt.show() 
    plt.savefig("db_index_vs_cluster.png")
```

However, I have been asked to use not the Daves-Bouldin index, but the raw distance between clusters. To do that, I need to calculate the average distance between clusters for all the values of "t". I have tried to use the functions `pdist` and `maxdist`. However, I haven't been able to obtain the average distance between clusters to plot similarly to the BD score. Can someone please tell me if I can do this?